# MIn hour of every hour

Tags: mysql, database

Hello everybody I have this set of data:

2019-02-21  16:15:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  16:00:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  15:45:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  15:30:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  15:15:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  15:00:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  14:45:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  14:30:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  13:45:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  13:30:00    1018.08
2019-02-21  13:15:00    1018.08

I need to get the min hour of every hour of this data for examample in hour 13 the min hour is 13:15, in 14 is 14:30 in 15 is 15:00 in 16 is 16:00.
Someone can help me?
Best regards

Comment: What format is that data in? What schema? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` helps here.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `datos` (
  `id_estacion` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_sensor` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_sensor` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dato` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8556 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: It's a lot easier to read in the body of your question with code-formatting applied, something you can do easily by indenting that with four spaces or using the `{}` auto-formatting button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT min(hora) FROM datos GROUP BY HOUR(hora)
```

Comment: You may have to also group by date.